# Remove all controls from a form

Tags: vb.net

I am programmatically adding several controls to a form in my project, then when a timer ticks, I want to remove all of the existing controls and replace them with new controls and new, updated data (as an aside - is this horrible coding?)

I had a look on msdn and found the controlcollection.clear() method which sounds like it will do what I want. However I get a rather cryptic "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference" error whenever I try to use the method.

Why does this happen? I am a newbie and I'm not sure what the non-shared member is (or what those are) or how to give it an object reference.

This is not the code I am using, but I think it illustrates the point most simply:

```
Private Sub add_and_remove()
    For i = 0 To 10
        Dim t As New TextBox
        t.Text = "whatever"
        Me.Controls.Add(t)
    Next
    Me.ControlCollection.Clear()
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `ControlCollection` is a type.  `Controls` is an instance of said `ControlCollection` type.  Beware that creating controls at runtime carried with it the responsibility of disposing of them lest your app will leak.

Comment: Oh, well that was easy haha! Thanks. Add that as an answer (use controls rather than controlcollection) and I'll accept it?

Comment: "remove all of the existing controls and replace them with new controls and new, updated data (as an aside - is this horrible coding?)" -- Almost certainly YES. Leave the controls in place, and update properties of the controls as needed.

Answer (score 2):

From comments: Use

`Me.Controls.Clear()` as opposed to `Me.ControlCollection.Clear()`

Or better still, don't clear the controls at all and just update the properties of the controls.

Thanks all!